# Java (Android) How to iterate with controls, in a LinearLayout with other LinearLayouts

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a LinearLayout with another 4 LinearLayouts..And these LinearLayouts have some checkboxes inside. I want to get the state (checked or not) of these checkboxes.. How can i do this?

regards!

Rafael

Comment: i need to save the data for specific ones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to get a reference to the parent LinearLayout, let us say that the parent LinearLayout is stored in a variable named "a". Next, you must assign an id to the child LinearLayout's and the checkboxes, using the android:id XML attribute. Let us assume that the child LinearLayout has an id of "b" and the check box you want the value of has an id of "c". You then say:

```
LinearLayout b = (LinearLayout)(a.findViewById(R.id.b));
CheckBox c = (CheckBox)(b.findViewById(R.id.c));
boolean checked = c.isChecked();
```

EDIT:
If you want to loop over it, just use for-loops:

```
//assume that "a" is your parent LinearLayout
ArrayList<CheckBox> allCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<LinearLayout> linearLayouts = new ArrayList<>;
for(int i = 0; i < linearLayouts.size())
{
    if(a.getChildAt(i) instanceof LinearLayout)
    {
        linearLayouts.add((LinearLayout)(a.getChildAt(i)));
    }
}
for(LinearLayout linearLayout : linearLayouts)
{
    ArrayList<CheckBox> checkBoxes= new ArrayList<>;
    for(int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.size())
    {
        if(linearLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox)
        {
            checkBoxes.add((CheckBox)(linearLayout.getChildAt(i)));
        }
    }
    allCheckBoxes.addAll(checkBoxes);
}
```

Now you have an `ArrayList<CheckBox>` called `allCheckBoxes` that you can call `CheckBox.isChecked()` on.

Comment: eagle, thanks for the answer, but i want to do a loop, iterating with many LinearLayouts, one inside another... I made the loop with one LinearLayout, but i dont know how to made a loop inside a loop..

Comment: I added some information on how you would loop over the LinearLayout to get the desired result.